# I think these functions are seminorms but not norms (in "Undergraduate Analysis" by Serge Lang)

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

[image]

I am reading "Undergraduate Analysis" by Serge Lang.
The above image is from "Problems and Solutions for Undergraduate Analysis" by Rami Shakarchi.

I think $\sigma_1 + \sigma_2$ and $\max(\sigma_1, \sigma_2)$ are seminorms but not norms.

Are both Serge Lang and Rami Shakarchi wrong?

Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong. What is the difference between a seminorm and a norm? The amount of elements with norm zero. Check that in both cases it indeed is only the zero element that has norm = 0. As Lang does in the proof.

Comment: @user587399 $\sigma_1(0) + \sigma_2(0) = 0 + \sigma_2(0) = \sigma_2(0)$. But I cannot derive $\sigma_2(0) = 0$.

Comment: A seminorm satisfies $\sigma_2(0)=0$ by definition

Comment: @Caffeine Thank you very much. $\sigma_2(0) = \sigma_2(0 \times 0)) = |0| \sigma_2(0)) = 0$.

Comment: Yes you can, a (semi)norm has a homogeneity property..

Comment: @user587399 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably forgetting that $\sigma_1$ is assumed to be  a norm. In both cases we have $\sigma_1(x)=0$ which implies that $x=0$.

Comment: $\sigma_1(0) + \sigma_2(0) = 0 + \sigma_2(0) = \sigma_2(0)$. But I cannot derive $\sigma_2(0) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much again, Kavi Rama Murthy.

Answer (score 1):

The missing step is possibly going from $\sigma_1(x)+\sigma_2(x)=0$ to $\sigma_1(x)=\sigma_2(x)=0$.

Part of the definition of (semi)norm is that $\sigma(x)\ge0$, for every $x$. Now, if the sum of two nonnegative numbers is zero, then both are zero.

For the other one, from $\max\bigl(\sigma_1(x),\sigma_2(x)\bigr)=0$ it also follows $\sigma_1(x)=\sigma_2(x)=0$, because
$$
0\le\max\bigl(\sigma_1(x),\sigma_2(x)\bigr)
$$
because of nonnegativity of (semi)norms.

Since $\sigma_1$ is assumed to be a norm, from $\sigma_1(x)=0$ we can deduce $x=0$.

Comment: egreg, Thank you for your answer.